# Comments on In Xcode 7 playground is not showing is markup format

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7, swift-playground

I am trying to change the format for comments into markup format introduced in Xcode 7 playgrounds. I have clicked rendered markup in "Editor -> Show Rendered Markup. It does show the comments already written in the playground in markup format but doesn't simultaneously convert the ones I create in it. In order for that to be converted into markup format, I either have to close the playground file or change it to raw markup and then back to rendered markup. Isn't it supposed to convert it into markup format the same instant I type a new comment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not the intention of the playground markdown. It is more like the message you type here in stackoverflow: The markdown is meant to be usable in plain text mode (when you type).

Also while you type, Playground is trying to execute your code, not update the playground display.

I think the behavior is intentional.

Comment: thank you! And more thing, can I change the font color in markdown comments?

Comment: TMK there is *no* font coloring available.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me in **Xcode 9.1**

**Rendered Markup**

- Clicking `Editor` -> `Show Rendered Markup`

**Raw Markup**

- Clicking `Editor` -> `Show Raw Markup`